# Sennheiser MKH 418S power adapter

Tags: microphone

What is the power adapter for Sennheiser MKH 418S Stereo Mic? I've an adapter MZA 14, provided by the reseller, but it gives a mono output only. Is there any other adaptor recommended for the same Mic for stereo output?

Comment: I don't actually know the mic, but I've seen them advertised with a Y-cable & 2 MZAs. I'd have a word with the seller, for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

418S does not have a power adapter. The mic presents a 5 pin XLR output. The pinout is as follows:

- 1 Ground
- 2,3 MID Balanced Signal (+/-)
- 4,5 SIDE Balanced Signal (+/-)

Both microphone capsules in the 418s are condensor, and consequently they are powered by +48v Phantom power between the Ground and the Mid/Side signal connectors respectively.

Comment: Not necessarlily 48V phantom. Could be T power.